# Properties of $f(x) = (e^x \sin(x), e^x \cos(x))$

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to understand why $f(x) = (e^x \sin(x), e^x \cos(x))$ isn't an homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^2$. I know that it can't be because $\mathbb{R} - {0}$ isn't connected, unlike $\mathbb{R}^2 - f(0)$.

It is continuous, but I'm not sure how to check if it is injective/surjective. Intuitively I think it is surjective since any relation is possible between $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: Your function isn't even surjective!

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain 
ok, how do you show that?

Comment: On every circle around the origin your function hits exactely one point.

Comment: If you identify $\mathbb R^2$ with $\mathbb C$ your function can be expressed as $i\exp((1-i)x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $|f(x)|=e^x$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$. This shows that your function is injective but not surjective (on every circle around the origin your function hits exactely one point).

Comment: Thanks.
Follow up question, is it an homeomorphism on its image? i.e is $f^{-1}$ continuous?
I'm pretty sure it is since any open interval is mapped by $f$ to an "open interval" on the "spiral image".

Comment: Yeah, it is. But if you take the closure of the image, you get the origin as additional point. So then you would have something homeomorphic to $[-\infty,\infty)$.